# Limitation of a shape

Tags: calculus

If a calculus question asked:

"If a rectangle has dimensions $(2r) \times (r)$, then four cuts of $(x) cm \times (x)$ cm were cut off the four corners, giving the new shape dimensions $(2r-2x)\times(r-2x)$. What would be a limitation of this new shape?"

Comment: Maybe they are asking what maximum volume will be occupied by resulting cuboid

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but yes, they asked that question. Thus, I found the derivative of x(2r-2x)(r-2x) and found the the value of x, which would result in the cuboid having a max volume. They then asked me to repeat the same process with (3r and r) and (4r and r). Then the part I don't understand is when they ask for me to "develop a conjecture between x (the cut to be made for the square) and the length of the rectangle such that the cake tin has a max volume". I was thinking it might have something to do with the values of x found and their limitations?